# Проблема с преобразование string в datetime

Tags: c#, строки, datetime

Возникла проблема при преобразовании переменной string в datetime.

Код:

```
Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application(); 
Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"путь", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 

Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];

Excel.Range last = ObjWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

Excel.Range range = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", last);

int lastUsedRow = last.Row;

for (int i = 1; i < last.Row; i++)
 {
    string colnum = Convert.ToString(i);           

    var exceldate = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("O" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();

    DateTime date_dt;
    date_dt = DateTime.Parse(exceldate);// ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА

    var date = date_dt.ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
   }
```

Ошибка на откоменнтированной строчке : "Данная строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime. Обнаружено неизвестное слово, начинающееся с индекса 0."

Чтение идет из excel файла, в столбце "O" которого находятся даты.
Например:
29.03.2018
29.03.2018

Цель преобразование - это вывод из excel даты в формате 29MAR18.

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ИНФОРМАЦИИ:

Почитал про то, как лучше перегонять даты из excel.
Советуют перегнать в double, а уже его в dstetime с помощью FRomOADate. 
Получается что то вроде:

```
var exceldate = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("O" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();
double exceldate_d = double.Parse(exceldate);//Ошибка
var date = DateTime.FromOADate(exceldate_d).ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Ошибка: "входная строка имела неверный формат". Пробовал добавить в parse cultureinfo. Например:

```
double exceldate_d = double.Parse(exceldate, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"));
```

или

```
double exceldate_d = double.Parse(exceldate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Но результат всё тот же. Никак не читается формат даты из excel.

Comment: какое значение у `exceldate` ?,можете добавить в текст вопрос

Comment: У exceldate значение 29.03.2018 в первом проходе цикла

Answer (score 1):

Парсим дату в формате "29MAR18":

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("29MAR18", "ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Парсим дату формата "29.03.2018" :

```
DateTime.Parse("29.03.2018", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"));
```

Нужно внимательно следить за культурой, которая используется при чтение даты. К примеру, если указать `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")`, то вы получите ошибку.

Comment: исходный формат `29.03.2018`

Comment: @tym32167 переписал, спасибо.